# Rebuild dataguard configuration when standby is broken

Tags: oracle, dataguard

I have an Oracle Data Guard configuration with two servers:

- oradb (physical)
- oradbstb (standby)

Both are running with Oracle 11g R2.

A few days ago I had problems with the standby (the server was turned off and the primary files were not received ... which were subsequently deleted).

I would like to know how to reconfigure the standby server from scratch. What would be the steps that I must carry out?

On the primary database I make a full backup with rman every Saturday and the rest of the days I make a backup of archives also with rman.

How should I go about restoring my standby database again? 
What steps should I follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't try to "restore" it.  I'd just blow it away and rebuild from scratch, just like you did when you built it the first time.

And take steps to prevent the problem from repeating.